# ”Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1125“， i tried verify=False， but it doesn't work

Tags: python, proxy, windows-10

”Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1125“， i tried verify=False， but it doesn't work

i readed the doc, it says "If the output of the above command isn’t empty and looks like this:

{
"http": "http://127.0.0.1:8888",
"https": "https://127.0.0.1:8888"  # <--- This setting is the problem!
}
Search how to configure proxies on your operating system and change the https://... URL into http://. After you make the change the return value of urllib.request.getproxies() should be:

{  # Everything is good here! :)
"http": "http://127.0.0.1:8888",
"https": "http://127.0.0.1:8888"
}
If you still can’t figure out how to configure your proxy after all these steps please join our community Discord and we’ll try to help you with your issue.

i got something helpful from "https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/1.26.x/advanced-usage.html#tls-warnings"

but i don't know how to configure my proxy,my system is windows 10.
if i don't configure my proxy, what do i change my code can make it works?

Comment: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/1.26.x/advanced-usage.html#tls-warnings